# How to fix .UnsatisfiedDependencyException error in Spring?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have the following code:

```kotlin
package com.example.demo

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.Table

@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}


@RestController
class MessageResource(var service: MessageService) {

    @GetMapping
    fun index(): List<Message> = service.findMessagesInDB()

    @PostMapping
    fun post(@RequestBody message: Message) {
        service.addMessageToDB(message)
    }
}


@Service
class MessageService(val db : MessageRepository) {

    fun findMessagesInDB(): List<Message> = db.findMessages()

    fun addMessageToDB(message: Message){
        db.save(message)
    }
}

@Repository
interface MessageRepository : CrudRepository<Message, String> {
    @Query("select * from messages")
    fun findMessages(): List<Message>
}


@Table(name ="MESSAGES")
@Entity
data class Message(@Id val id: String?, val text: String)
```

I get

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.MessageRepository.findMessages()!

I followed this kotlin-Spring tutorial: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/jvm-spring-boot-restful.html#add-database-support

Comment: read the full error message, your issue is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.MessageRepository.findMessages()!`. Start from here.

Comment: I tired things on that function but with no success. I tried to remove the querry as follows
```@Repository
interface MessageRepository : CrudRepository<Message, String> {
 fun findMessages() = findAll().toList()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that a `nativeQuery = true` attribute is missing in your `@Query`. Try the following:

```kotlin
@Repository
interface MessageRepository : CrudRepository<Message, String> {
    @Query(value = "select * from messages", nativeQuery = true)
    fun findMessages(): List<Message>
}
```

Additionally, this custom `@Query` method seems unnecessary, since `CrudRepository` has a method (`findAll()`) that does exactly that.

Comment: Even without the query,  with `fun findMessages() = findAll().toList()` I am getting the same error.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: I did and it works. Thanks ! How to properly remove the query?

Comment: You either remove `@Query` and the method or you remove only `@Query` but then you need to follow some patterns in the method name (see details at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation and https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords). If my answer helped you consider upvoting it and accept it as the answer so that others can benefit from it. Thanks!